# coffee compiler not found by xcode?

Tags: xcode, node.js, cordova, coffeescript

I used to work with ubuntu and quite new to mac and xcode. I am trying to build cordova-true-native-ios (https://github.com/mschulkind/cordova-true-native-ios) on my mac air. But I have error message when trying to run the example:

scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin coffee -c -p CoffeeScripts/action_sheet_demo.coffee >   www/action_sheet_demo.js
sh: coffee: command not found
scons: *** [www/action_sheet_demo.js] Error 127
scons: building terminated because of errors.

It looks to me that the /bin/bash cannot find coffee compiler within scons. But I installed nodejs from nvm and then use npm to install coffee-script module. I also added the following in my .bash_profile:

. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use v0.8.4

So I have no problem calling coffee within my terminal. But I guess I miss some linking or command for xcode.

Answer (score 7):

Could it be that you did not install coffee scritp globaly

try:

```
npm install -g coffee-script
```

the -g is important here you want and need it.

Open a terminal and test if you have the coffee bin installed and accessible in your path.
Coffe should be in /usr/local/bin/ and it seems to already be in you path.

Comment: Hi 3on, thanks for reply. I tried: npm install -g coffee-script. But coffee isn't in the /usr/local/bin. But I can call it from terminal. Unfortunately, xcode still fails to build the code.

Comment: yes, I did sudo npm install. It still doesn't help. I mean the coffee binary file isn't in /usr/local/bin. Instead, it's in the ~/.nvm/v0.8.4/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just solved the problem by myself. In scons' script, I modified the 'coffee' to the specific 'coffee' path on my machine. It turns out the building passes.